# In MAML for RL, are new tasks sampled for every meta update, or is the same set of tasks used throughout?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, machine-learning, meta-learning, model-agnostic-meta-learning

Consider Model Agnostic Meta-Learning, as described [here](https://paperswithcode.com/method/maml).

For a RL task $T_i$, represented with a model $f$, with parameters $\theta$ and learning rate $\alpha$, where the RL loss function is $\mathcal{L}$:

$$
 \theta'_{i} = \theta - \alpha\nabla_{\theta}\mathcal{L}_{\mathcal{T}_{i}}\left(f_{\theta}\right)
$$

This is standard gradient descent.

The meta-update step samples multiple tasks $\mathcal{T}_i\sim p(\mathcal{T})$, calculates their respective parameters $\theta_i$ from $\theta$, and minimizes the loss of the original $\theta$ with respect to these intermediate $\theta_i$s:

$$
 \min_{\theta} \sum_{\mathcal{T}_{i} \sim p\left(\mathcal{T}\right)} \mathcal{L}_{\mathcal{T_{i}}}\left(f_{\theta'_{i}}\right) = \sum_{\mathcal{T}_{i} \sim p\left(\mathcal{T}\right)} \mathcal{L}_{\mathcal{T_{i}}}\left(f_{\theta - \alpha\nabla_{\theta}\mathcal{L}_{\mathcal{T}_{i}}\left(f_{\theta}\right)}\right)  \\
 \theta \leftarrow \theta - \beta\nabla_{\theta} \sum_{\mathcal{T}_{i} \sim p\left(\mathcal{T}\right)} \mathcal{L}_{\mathcal{T_{i}}}\left(f_{\theta'_{i}}\right)
$$

Quesstion: is $\mathcal{T}_i\sim p(\mathcal{T})$ sampling done for every meta-update? Or, is a constant set of tasks maintained from the beginning? Can the frequency of task sampling be different from the frequency of meta-updates?

Comment: definitely sampled from a bigger pool of tasks, otherwise bye bye generalization